# OS.walk prints my files in a random order, how can i sort the values?

Tags: python, os.walk

I am trying to export six images from a folder the six images are called 1.png, 2.png etc
but when I call os.walk and ask to print the files they come out in a random order:

```
/Users/claudiabergeron/Documents/Python/Python_VideoGame_3.10/bin/python "/Users/claudiabergeron/Documents/Python/Tutoriels/Video games/Pygame/Platformer/help.py"
('/Users/claudiabergeron/Documents/Python/Tutoriels/Video games/Pygame/Platformer/graphics/character/run', [], ['4.png', '5.png', '6.png', '2.png', '3.png', '1.png'])
```

Here is the code:

```
from os import walk
def import_folder(path):

    for information in walk(path):
        print(information)

import_folder('/Users/leolepage/Documents/Python/Tutoriels/Video games/Pygame/Platformer/graphics/character/run')
```

Does anybody know what should I do?

Comment: Build a list of all files in a directory(ies), and then call `random.shuffle` to randomize the element order.

Comment: I do not want to randomize the elements I want the element to appear in order

Comment: On second thought, after reading thru the question more carefully, looks like you want to *sort* the file names instead?

Comment: yes i do want to do that

Comment: In that case, please either update the title or provide a sample desired output. I was basing my comment off the question title actually.

Comment: how do I do that

Comment: you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70055988/edit) the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

os.walk uses os.listdir and cannot be sorted. i would suggest you use os.listdir and sort it:

```
from os import listdir
def import_folder(path):
    for information in sorted(listdir(path)):
        print(information)
```